# web-scraping fix bad character symbol

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

to begin, i'm french so sorry if my english isn't perfect.

I'm role player and i need to scraper this http://www.gemmaline.com/sorts/liste-classe-pretre.htm which is in Iso-8859-1
to catch each text list and later to catch each information from each link from name list.
i have already formulas on google sheet to scraper it. But like lot of know, importxml in google sheet it's 50 request max, and it's very slow. So i try a different process with javascript and node js. To use axios and cheerio to scraper.
It works but the result is uncorrect for each accented character or single quote. And after lot of try i didn't solve my issue. This is the code:

```js
const PORT = 8000
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express()

const url = 'http://www.gemmaline.com/sorts/liste-classe-pretre.htm'

axios(url)
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const data = []

        $('body:nth-child(2) ul li').each(function() {
            
            //const encoder = new TextEncoder()
            //const name = new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array(encoder.encode($(this).text())))

            const name = $(this).text()
            const url = $(this).find('a').attr('href')

            data.push({ name, url})
        })

        fs.writeFileSync('test.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 1))
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

    

app.listen(PORT, ()=>console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

and this is my result in a file, btw it's the same if i did just a console.log(data):

[image: result]

Now you can see strange symbol. If someone know how to fix it, i will be really happy.

Comment: I would guess that your text is some variation of unicode (UTF-8 probably) and that the characters that get mangled are encoded using multiple bytes that won't be convertible to a UInt8 value (0-255).

Comment: yes the website is in Iso-8859-1, i add this information to the main post

Comment: Unless you specifiy the character encoding `fs.writeFileSync` writes the file as utf8 - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-writefilesync-method/. You will need to either convert the text to UTF8 or specify the ISO-8859-1 encoding

Comment: i tried this `fs.writeFileSync('test.json', JSON.stringify(articles, null, 1), {encoding: "latin1"})` but it's now `ý` instead of `�`. i tried also some thing to convert directly in utf8 but i think i did it badly, it was the code in commentary in the main post

Comment: Ah, okay. by default `TextDecoder` assumes the source is utf-8 [see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) You should probably try `new TextDecoder('iso-8859-1')`

Answer (score 1):

it works !

```js
const PORT = 8000
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express()

const url = 'http://www.gemmaline.com/sorts/liste-classe-pretre.htm'


axios(url, {
    
    responseEncoding: 'binary'
})
    .then(response => {

        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data.toString('ISO-8859-1'),{decodeEntities: false})
        const data = []

        $('body:nth-child(2) ul li').each(function() {

            const name = $(this).text()
            const url = $(this).find('a').attr('href')

            data.push({ name, url })
        })

        fs.writeFileSync('test2.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 1))
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

[wrong character line 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRXc6.png)

I have now a new issue, a single quote at line 11 should be not become ’. On this line it's normaly `Conservation d'organe Nécromancie` instead of `Conservation dorgane Nécromancie`.
After, i could just substitute this symbol by a single quote for each time i get it but maybe we can find something more clean directly by encoding

Comment: for the moment I just have this code to solve the problem `const name = $(this).text().replace('', "'")`` even if i think there is a better method

Comment: Its not very clear what the fix was here, if you could update it? :D